# Ubuntu 10.04 reinstall

Tags: ubuntu

I know that the real answer is to upgrade to 16.10, but I have been told that I will lose all the emails in evolution.
I am having problems with gradually losing things and have now lost the ability to connect to either wi-fi or Ethernet.
It does work if I use my original download on a memory stick so it is not a hardware issue.
What will happen if I reinstall version 10.04? Will I lose data or emails. I have all my data files backed up to a external drive. But not emails. I am thinking of a short term solution till SWMBO can sort out her important emails. Then I will start again with 16.10

Comment: If you have done the backup of your entire user /home/ folder you will have also the backup of the emails

Comment: What makes you think that your user profile (incl. locally stored e-mails) will be lost during a (proper) system upgrade or even reinstallation of Ubuntu? You're welcome to ask how to do that either here or over on [AskUbuntu](//askubuntu.com/). Also, why do you have e-mails stored locally *only*? Every half-decent mail server out there in the last decade speaks IMAP which synchronizes e-mails (among other things) between the server and one or more clients.

Comment: I was told here that I would not be able to import my emails into the new version of evolution.

Comment: We don't keep all the old emails on the server, but delete them when down!Laced to save space in the inbox which would be overflowing by now.

Comment: Are you saying an upgrade to 16.10 will just overwrite the OS and not touch the data?

Comment: If you are "losing things" as you wrote, you should IMMEDIATELY back up your home directory as it may possibly indicate some problems with the hard drive/file system on your computer. Make sure your email directory (I presume it's `~/.evolution`?) is saved, as well. Once your data is saved on some external medium such as a flash drive, you won't have to worry about losing your data under any circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

If your home directory, aka `/home`, is on a different partition than root, you can safely reinstall Ubuntu 10.04

You can ask the installer to mount the partition without formatting it, therefore all emails are kept.